# Parsing String Information android?

Tags: android, string, parsing

I got response from webservice like

```
<response>*null 41 23085A49 Madhu 919703473353 1234#</response>.
```

I want to display my name and mobile number into two edit text fields which I have created. Can you please tell me how can I update these fields?

Comment: Are you able to alter the webservice?

Comment: If you can modify the webservice, I would recommend you to respond with json as it will be easier to parse your information

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
String args[] = your_webserver_response_as_a_string.split("\\s"); //split on whitespace characters
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext1)).setText(args[3]);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext2)).setText(args[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to get a proper response from the Web Service that you are working with.
For example you need to get a standard data format like XML or JSON.
And after getting a standardized response like that you can parse that response in your application via using a XML or JSON Parser and use it in a way that you please.

Answer (score 0):

Format seems like "value1 value2 value3 name number value5".

```
string = string.subString(0,string.lastIndexof(" "));
number = String subString(string.lastIndexof(" "));
string = string.subString(0,string.lastIndexof(" "));
name = String subString(string.lastIndexof(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Its easy to implement and a great and simple protocol.
Using a string splitter is possible but it can become a big mess.